# Solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=\cos(x(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

**Question**: Solve $$\frac{dx}{d t}=1$$$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\cos(x(t))$$
Where $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$

**Answer**: I have gotten $x(t)=t+x_0$, cant seem to get $y(t)$ should be a simple problem, but just cant do it.

Comment: is not $y = \sin(t+x_0) + C$ now set the initial condition $y_0 = \sin(x_0) + C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$y^\prime(t) = cos(t+x_0)$$ Thus: $$\begin{align} y(t) &  = y_0 + \int_0^t y^\prime(\tilde t) d\tilde t \\ & = y_0 + \int_0^t \cos(\tilde t+x_0) d\tilde t \\ & = y_0 + [\sin(\tilde t + x_0)]_0^t \\ & = y_0 + \sin(t+x_0)-\sin(x_0)\end{align}$$